# Leaflet circleMarkers don´t show up

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, flask, zurb-foundation, leaflet

I am trying to draw hundres of circleMarker in a Leaflet map, I am using flask and foundation.js, the same code work in different app built with bootstrap.js

This is my code:

```
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([40,-4], 6);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-cnkhv76j/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery  <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(map);

    var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 100,
    fillColor: "#FFF803",
    color: "#DDFF03",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 0.8,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
    };

    {% for item in data['data'] %}        
    L.circleMarker([{{item[0]}},{{item[1]}}],geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(map);
    {% endfor %} 

    var marker = L.marker([41.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup("I am a circle.");
    var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {color: 'red',
                                                fillColor: '#f03',
                                                fillOpacity: 1
                                                }).addTo(map); 
</script>
```

At the bottom I tried a fixed marker which appears and fixed circle which doesn´t, could it be a problem with foundation.js? Because in a previous project with other framework worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ilja, many thanks. You were right the circles were pushed behind the map by a css. In this case, I was also using d3.js for some chart, and as soon as I got rid of nvd3's css the circles showed up.

Comment: Traditionally, since Ilja answered your question, you would mark his response as the answer, not your response where you thank him.

Answer (score 5):

I [tried your code](http://jsfiddle.net/XMnmw/), replacing `51.508` with `41.508` (so the red circle is near the marker) and adding just a single circleMarker. It works. So the problem is not in the code.

Please check that you have included `leaflet.css` from the same locations as `leaflet.js`. Also check there are no errors in a javascript console (Ctrl+Shift+J in Firefox). Check that coordinates from `{{item[0/1]}}` are properly formatted (decimal separator is a dot, no extra symbols). Try using more recent version of Leaflet library, 0.7.3.

Comment: Thanks Ilja, I have checked what you said, I have the latest verions, marker objects are drawn. However, when using circle or circleMarker, all objects appear on the code, but are not drawn. I already had this kind of issue when using Rshiny and leaflet, but I gave up. However, I can give up!!!

Comment: Can you post an example of rendered `L.circleMarker([{{item[0]}},{{item[1]}}], ...` line?

Comment: Ilja, this a snippet of code which has been captured from chrome's console. `L.circleMarker([-22.5373252,-55.73210504],geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(map);              
      L.circleMarker([11.38078685,-72.23666527],geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(map);              
      L.circleMarker([38.85640728,-6.31787715],geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(map);              
      L.circleMarker([19.361074,-99.183199],geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(map);      
      L.circleMarker([-33.42463625,-70.61157703],geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(map);`

Comment: It seems to me that they are fine, aren´t they?

Comment: This works perfectly, markers show up. `L.marker([-22.5373252,-55.73210504],geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(map);                    
                    L.marker([11.38078685,-72.23666527],geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(map);                        
                    L.marker([38.85640728,-6.31787715],geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(map);                          
                    L.marker([19.361074,-99.183199],geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(map);                         `

Comment: They are perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/XMnmw/1/ Please look for a bug elsewhere.

Comment: Could this comment in the javascript console a bug?                       `Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (min-resolution: 144dpi) leaflet.js:6` I have checked in my previous app where it worked, and it also appears.

Comment: It also appears this comment: `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/social/conversation/bigdata?source=geo". leaflet.js:6
o.DomUtil.getStyle leaflet.js:6
o.Map.o.Class.extend._initLayout leaflet.js:6
o.Map.o.Class.extend.initialize leaflet.js:6
e leaflet.js:6
o.map leaflet.js:6
(anonymous function) bigdata?source=geo:134` But I think this is related to the images layer. The only difference between my previous app, where it worked and this one, is that the first one was built with bootstrap and this one with foundation. Cheers

Comment: No, I think not. It's just a warning. The second one also doesn't ring a bell. Can foundation be shadowing some of `L.CircleMarker`'s functions?

Comment: I have double checked the dom and the elements appear:                     `<svg class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="900" height="500" viewBox="-90 -50 900 500" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(-90px, -50px, 0px);"><g><path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#DDFF03" stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="1" fill="#FFF803" fill-opacity="0.8" d="M374,172.5A1.5,1.5,0,1,1,373.9,172.5 z" class="leaflet-clickable"></path></g> ...<g></g>` Is there anything missing in here?

Comment: Nope, the same as in that jsfiddle I've referenced 5 comments ago. Maybe svgs are pushed underneath the map by css?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue, and it turns out that it is the nv.d3.css file. I found that commenting out these lines will allow you to draw a circle:

```
display: block; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;'
```

I don't know what potential side effects this might have on your page, but I think the main issue is that d3 decides to hijack any svgs that you put on the page.

EDIT: my case was with circles, but I wouldn't be surprised if it is the same problem between circles and circle markers.

EDIT 2:
It's been a while, but someone just liked this, so I feel like I should inform you that in the end, these didn't play nice together. I didn't have the time to really tinker with it, so I was forced to remove the leaflet circles and pass on the project with a recommendation that it might just be easier to plug in Google Maps. Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That question was posted long ago.
But May my answer helps someone.

When we instanciate *L.CircleMarker(...)*, the circle is created, but not showing.
In my case, i noticed that it wait for the window resize event in order to display.
So juste trigger that event after *L.CircleMarker(...).addTo(map)* and the circle will appear like a charm.

With JS

```
 window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

With Jquery

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```