# LEAFLET: WHY circleMarker doesnt working for me

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet

I tried to search for resolution, my code but i cannot found this problem. If i use `L.marker` it work 3000 data but it slowed my program. And if I used `L.circleMarker` for 3000 data is doesn't display it.

I am stuck at this issue for two days now. please help, thank you.

```js
    var map = L.map('map', {
        renderer: L.canvas()
    }).setView([-0.789275, 113.921327], 5);
    L.tileLayer(
        'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            minZoom: 5,
            fullscreenControl: true,
            preferCanvas: true,
            interactive: true
        }).addTo(map)

    var myRenderer = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5
    });
    L.circleMarker([-6.37245739, 107.6659878], {
            renderer: myRenderer,
            dashArray: "4 4",
        }).addTo(map).bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
```

[image]

Comment: if there are no errors logged to console, this could be an issue with your css imports. [see if this helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24406053/9583747)

Comment: thanks for the response. but I still don't understand how to solve it from the question you posted. For example window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); , I copied this and pasted it under L.circlemarker and it's not working. I also don't have d3.css. So is there any other solution?.
by the way, I've read the question before making mine.
one more thing, I actually use the dashboard theme "dashliteAdmin. I didn't try to change their style for fear it will change how my other program styles. But if there are small changes and have a note where I changed it maybe that's okay

Comment: that's right, no error in console. and impor leaflet no problem,

Comment: What if you try without specifying a renderer?

Comment: if I remove the renderer , still nothing happens.

Comment: if it's L.marker it will appear immediately but if it's L.circle or L.circleMarker. it never worked. on the console also nothing happens, so I don't know how it is.

Comment: Is working with the latest Leaflet Version [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/zgenNV0OkCOJJbmK). Do you get `1.8.0` if you call `console.log(L.version)`? Else it is maybe a problem of your css. CircleMarkers are rendered as `svg`, Marker as `img`

Comment: yeah right i got the latest version, meaning it's located in css. I turned off the css theme and got a circle marker. Yeaa which part for me should I change so that the circle appears in the current theme?   [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UEVidRpn2bWTmRO-jbQWmm40HYDhGzVa/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Do any of you know that? actually for myself, do not know that part. Because what I know is only basic css. this very hard to me.      or don't need to change something, is there any css I need to make on the map part? for the circle marker to appear?